# JavaScriptの配列について

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptの配列について教えてください。

```
itemsA = [{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},
            {id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:""},
            {id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:""}];

itemsB = [{name:"b"},
            {name:"b"},
            {name:"c"}];
```

上記のような２つの配列から、以下の配列を作成したいです。
( itemsAとitemsBの配列で、同じ「name」があるデータのみ、「flg:"1"」としたいです )

```
results = [{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},
            {id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:"1"},
            {id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:"1"}];
```

色々試しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
ご教授の程、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `itemsA`の要素は`{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""}`ではなく`{id:"1", name:"a", flg:""}`とかではないですか？(`results`のほうも)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり、{id:"1", name:"a", flg:""}でした。（記載ミスでした）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

検索条件の `itemsB` は検索に向いたデータ構造ではないので、検索用のオブジェクト `inB` に最初に詰め替えます。

```js
itemsA = [{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},
        {id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:""},
        {id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:""}];
itemsB = [{name:"b"},
        {name:"b"},
        {name:"c"}];
results = [];

// 検索用オブジェクトに詰め替え:
let inB = {};
itemsB.forEach(function(b) {
    inB[b.name] = !!b.name;
});

for (let i = 0; i < itemsA.length; i += 3) {
  let id = itemsA[i].id, name = itemsA[i + 1].name, flg = itemsA[i + 2].flg;

  // itemsB に name があれば、flg = "1"
  inB[name] && (flg = "1");

  results.push({id: id}, {name: name}, {flg: flg});
}

console.log(results);
```

また質問の前提条件にある `itemsA` ですが、配列内で連続している `id, name, flg` が一対一の関係にあるデータ構造でしょうか。
一対一の関係をもったデータは、letrec さんのコメントにもあったように `{id: "1", name: "a", flg: ""}` とする方が、より自明な良いデータ構造になります。

もしデータ構造を変更する場合は、上記コードの for 文を変更してください。

```
for (let i = 0; i < itemsA.length; i++) {
    let id = itemsA[i].id, name = itemsA[i].name, flg = itemsA[i].flg;

    // itemsB に name があれば、flg = "1"
    inB[name] && (flg = "1");

    results.push({id: id, name: name, flg: flg});
}
```

Comment: rouさん、ご回答ありがとうございました！
おかげ様で無事解決することがでしました。

Answer (score 0):

## 元々の構造を維持した場合

オブジェクトの構造で疑問に思う部分は多々ありますが、元の構造を尊重するなら `{name:"***"}` が存在する index が「**1 + 3 * N**」で表せる事に注目して下さい。

```js
'use strict';
function generateItems1 (itemsA, itemsB) {
  const keys = new Set(itemsB.map(object => object.name));
  const items = itemsA.slice();

  for (let i = 1, len = items.length; i < len; i += 3) {
if (keys.has(items[i].name)) {
  items[i + 1].flg = '1';
}
  }

  return items;
}

const itemsA = [{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},{id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:""},{id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:""}];
const itemsB = [{name:"b"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"}];
const items = generateItems1(itemsA, itemsB);

console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // [{"id":"1"},{"name":"a"},{"flg":""},{"id":"2"},{"name":"b"},{"flg":"1"},{"id":"3"},{"name":"c"},{"flg":"1"}]
console.log(JSON.stringify([{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},{id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:"1"},{id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:"1"}]) === JSON.stringify(items));  // true
```

## 構造を変更した場合 (配列版)

letrec さんが指摘されたように、構造を変更した場合のコードです。

```js
'use strict';
function generateItems2 (itemsA, itemsB) {
  const keys = new Set(itemsB.map(object => object.name));
  const items = [];

  for (let i = 0, len = itemsA.length; i < len; i += 3) {
    const item = Object.assign({}, itemsA[i], itemsA[i + 1], itemsA[i + 2]);

    if (keys.has(item.name)) {
      item.flg = '1';
    }

    items.push(item);
  }

  return items;
}

const itemsA = [{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},{id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:""},{id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:""}];
const itemsB = [{name:"b"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"}];
const items = generateItems2(itemsA, itemsB);

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));  // [{"id":"1","name":"a","flg":""},{"id":"2","name":"b","flg":"1"},{"id":"3","name":"c","flg":"1"}]
```

## 構造を変更した場合 (Map版)

ユニークな id を key にした Map オブジェクトを作ります。

```js
'use strict';
function generateItems3 (itemsA, itemsB) {
  const keys = new Set(itemsB.map(object => object.name));
  const items = new Map;

  for (let i = 0, len = itemsA.length; i < len; i += 3) {
    const item = Object.assign({}, itemsA[i], itemsA[i + 1], itemsA[i + 2]);

    if (keys.has(item.name)) {
      item.flg = '1';
    }

    items.set(item.id, item);
  }

  return items;
}

const itemsA = [{id:"1"},{name:"a"},{flg:""},{id:"2"},{name:"b"},{flg:""},{id:"3"},{name:"c"},{flg:""}];
const itemsB = [{name:"b"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"}];
const items = generateItems3(itemsA, itemsB);

console.log(JSON.stringify([...items.entries()]));  // [["1",{"id":"1","name":"a","flg":""}],["2",{"id":"2","name":"b","flg":"1"}],["3",{"id":"3","name":"c","flg":"1"}]]

const item1 = items.get('1'); // id = "1" のオブジェクトを得る
console.log(item1);  // {id: "1", name: "a", flg: ""}
```

Re: Taka M さん

Comment: これを実行すると`name:"b"`の`flg`が2になります。先に`itemB`の重複を取り除く必要がありそうです。

Comment: @ mao ご指摘頂いた件、要件の認識が誤っていました。
flg は name 値の出現回数ではなく、name の存在フラグなのですね('1' = true / '' = false)。
親記事のコードを修正しました。

Comment: think49さん、maotさん、ご回答ありがとうございました！
おかげ様で無事解決することがでしました。